# How to check month number?

Tags: python

I have a current month number in format: `dd` as `01, 02...12`.

And incoming month as `01` or `1`.

How to check if imcoming month is less then current month?

Comment: you can convert it to int: `int(incoming_month) < int(current_month)`

Comment: It depends what the data types are. If they are both strings **and** they're 2 characters or if they're both integers then you'll just need to compare with < (less than). Otherwise you may need to normalise the values - probably to *int*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast your month to int first.

```
dd = "01"
if int(dd) < month:
    pass
```